# Syntax highlighting gone when using buffer

Tags: syntax-highlighting, buffers, filetype-java

At work I usually keep only a few files in buffer, typically a Yang file, a Java file, and possibly something like a readme file. In such an environment, the Yang syntax highlighting does not work. Example "run":

```
$ vim yangfile.yang # Yang syntax highlighting works
:e Foo.java         # new or existing file, doesnt'matter
:bnext              # Yang syntax highlighting is gone, all text is white
:so ~/.vimrc        # this does not work
```

My `.vimrc` is quite small, it starts with `source ~/yang.vim` (this file is available [here](http://www.yang-central.org/twiki/pub/Main/YangTools/yang.vim)) and then less than 50 more lines of pretty basic Vim configurations (I can edit my question to include the entire `.vimrc` on request).

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I think your setup is wrong—if that’s a syntax file, it should go into the syntax directory in one of the locations on your `runtimepath`. Then having `syntax on` in your vimrc will automatically load syntax highlighting (you may also need `filetype plugin on`; i cant remember).

Comment: Thanks. Where is the runtimepath? `:set runtimepath?` spit out several paths, `~/.vim` was one of them. I moved my syntax file there, added `syntax on` to `.vimrc`, highlighting did not work, added `filetype plugin on`, didn't work either. More suggestions? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to David Ben Knoble's comment I was able to find relevant information and solve my problem. I did as follows and it worked for me:

In `.vimrc`, remove `source ~/yang.vim`, add `:syntax on` and `:filetype plugin on` (I added them to the top of the file). Inside vim (normal mode), type `:set runtimepath?`. In my case one of the directories printed was `~/.vim`. Move `yang.vim` to `~/.vim/syntax` (create if needed). Finally, create `~/.vim/ftdetect/yang.vim` (create subdir if needed) and enter the following in that file:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.yang set filetype=yang
```

Done and done. Useful links:

[Vim 101: runtimepath](https://medium.com/usevim/vim-101-runtimepath-83194d411b0a)

[Creating your own syntax files](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files)

Comment: Well done! Glad you could solve the problem. Dont forget to mark it as answered